# Where can I find rare video of 2004 tsunami?

Tags: indonesia, disasters

I really am not sure if this is on topic but here goes

I am looking for a rare angle of the [Indian Ocean Tsunami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Indian_Ocean_earthquake_and_tsunami). I say it is rare because firstly, it is probably one of the very few images showing the exceedingly large tsunami waves as they approach Aceh, and secondly while I have read about this tape in a research paper, I simply cannot find it.

The video was filmed on Uteuen Badeue, on the eastern end of Banda Aceh Bay. The author was the chief of the Fishery Regional Office, atop a cliff

It is said to show 11 waves.

See [researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233416681_Reconstruction_of_Tsunami_Inland_Propagation_on_December_26_2004in_Banda_Aceh_Indonesia_through_Field_Investigations)

Possible candidates

- [Clip 1](https://youtu.be/2ozmwEBOmJo?t=789)
- [Clip 2](https://youtu.be/3LKSb7R6IrY?t=394)
- [Clip 3](https://youtu.be/zacJL66obug)
- [Clip 4](https://youtu.be/xFA8uVLT-6Q)

**Edit:** Author of the oaper Franck Lavigne responded.

> Halo pak,
> sayangnya videonya hilang, dicuri sama orang asing katanya. Jada saya nonton cuma ombak2 yg terakhir, cuma videonya tidak dikasih EmojiEmojiEmoji

Which Google translates to:

> Hello, sir,
> unfortunately the video is gone, stolen by a stranger he said. So I watched only the last waves, but the video didn't have EmojiEmojiEmoji

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors of the linked paper?

Comment: Good suggestion, and if that doesn't work, ask at TV stack exchange